TFLite model always predicting image probability 1.0
I trained a Keras CNN model (binary classification) on a custom image dataset. The accuracy of the model on test dataset came to be 90.53% (also fyi, precision=90.68%, f1_score=91.55). Since I intend to use this model on a mobile device, I post-training quantized it using TFLite (followed this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#float16_quantization).
After quantization, the model returns a prediction probability of 1 always, no matter what image is fed.
I have not performed any preprocessing on the images before loading to either of the models.
Code snippet:
test_ds = tf.keras.utils.load_img(os.path.join(path_data, "bg", img), target_size=(224, 224, 3))
test_ds = np.expand_dims(np.array(test_ds, dtype=np.float32), axis=0) # Since this is expected from the interpreter (check in_details)
    
# Load interpreter
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
in_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
out_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
        
# Resize input and output tensors based on how many images you'll feed at once (by default it's 1)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(in_details[0]["index"], (1, 224, 224, 3))
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(out_details[0]["index"], (1, 1))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
        
# Inference
interpreter.set_tensor(in_details[0]["index"], test_ds)
interpreter.invoke()
pred = interpreter.get_tensor(out_details[0]["index"])[0][0]

in_details:
[{'name': 'serving_default_conv2d_14_input:0',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ -1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

out_details:
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
  'index': 10,
  'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([-1,  1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]


Can you print() the "in_details" and "out_deails"? Also how did you PTQ it?

From the in/out details the only unusual issue I see in your code is the resize_tensor(). So comment out
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(in_details[0]["index"], (1, 224, 224, 3))
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(out_details[0]["index"], (1, 1))
and check if that solves your issue.

@Farmaker Still the same, buddy. The step is trivial in this context but later I'd like to read 100 images in a batch.
